# Is there type casting in VDM++?

Tags: casting, type-conversion, formal-methods, vdm++

For example, I want to cast **nat** to **seq of char** in VDM++.

In the code below, I want operation setValueOfX to return `"X is {value of q}"`, if q is of type nat and q < 3.

```
class A1

instance variables
    private x : nat := 0;


operations
    
    public setValueOfX : nat ==> seq of char
        setValueOfX(q) ==
        (
            if is_nat(q) and q < 3
                then
                (
                    x := q;

                    -- The following line doesn't work
                    -- return "X is " ^ q;
                )
            else
                return "Invalid value! Value of x must be more than 0 and less than 3.";
        );

end A1
```

I've tried using `^` but I got the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61IN4.png):

> Error[207] : Rhs of '^' is not a sequence type
> act : nat
> exp : ( seq1 of # | [] )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't implicitly convert values like that in VDM.

If you just want to see the result in a textural form, you could look at the IO library, which lets you "print" a mixture of types to the console. Alternatively, if you must return a string, you could specify a function that converts a nat to a decimal string, and the return "Result is" ^ nat2str(q).

Comment: Thank you for the IO library suggestion. Unfortunately, I can not use VDM10.

Comment: IO isn't a vdm10 feature, if that's what you meant. What tool are you using?

Comment: I see. I'm using VDM++ Toolbox Lite v8.0

Comment: I didn't understand why you mentioned VDM10. The "nat2str" idea was that you could write your own function to do that (just a few lines)